# Supremum over dense subset

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory

I'm interested about the following supremum:

$$\sup_{g\in A}E[-gf]$$

where $A\subset\{g\in L^1:g\ge 0,E[g]=1\}$ and $f\in L^\infty$ is fixed. $E$ denotes the expectation, i.e. it is the integral with respect to a finite measure. If I have a dense subset $B$ of $A$ in the $L^1$ sense. Is the following true:

$$\sup_{g\in A}E[-gf]=\sup_{h\in B}E[-hf]$$

$"\ge"$ is trivial, since $B\subset A$. For the other inequality, I need to use the density property. I know that I can finde a sequence $h_n$ in $B$ such that $-fh_n\to -fg$ in $L^1$ for a $g\in A$. My approach was:

$$E[-fg]\le E[|fg|]=\lim_nE[|h_nf|]\le\sup_{h\in B}E[|hf|]$$

The problem is that on the RHS I have $|\cdot|$ instead of $E[-fh]$. How can I fix my argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you actually have to prove is that 
$$\inf_{g\in A}E(gf)=\inf_{h\in B}E(hf).$$
Fix $\varepsilon>0$, there is $g\in A$ such that $E(gf)<\inf_{g\in A}E(gf)+\varepsilon$. Take $h\in B$ such that $E|g-h|<\varepsilon$. Then 
$$\inf_{h\in B}E(hf)\leqslant E(hf)\leqslant \varepsilon\lVert f\rVert_\infty+E(gf)<\varepsilon(\lVert f\rVert_\infty+1)+\inf_{g\in A}E(gf).$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you explain, why the second inequality is true?

Comment: ah I got it: $E(hf)=E((h-g+g)f)\le E(|f||h-g|)+E(gf)\le\|f\|\epsilon+ E(fg)$